# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado PERO EL ARCHIVO EXISTE

Tags: python, archivo, eliminar

Estoy intentando remover un archivo xls de forma automática y recibo el error

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el
> archivo especificado

Mi código es algo asi:

```
##Elimino el archivo anterior 

ubicacion = (r"C:\Users\rbisa\OneDrive\Escritorio\prueba_eliminar.xls")
 
try:
     shutil.rmtree(ubicacion) except OSError as e:
     print(f"Error:{ e.strerror}")
```

Probé tambien con:

```
remove(ubicacion)
```

Y con:

```
import os

ubicacion = (r"C:\Users\rbisa\OneDrive\Escritorio\prueba_eliminar.xls")
 
try:

        os.remove(ubicacion) 
    
    except OSError as e:
        print("Error de archivo: {}".format(e))
```

El archivo efectivamente existe en el disco, el path es correcto y tengo permisos de administrador. Probé de cambiarlo de ubicación y sigo recibiendo el mismo error. Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: con el explorador de archivo ve hasta la ruta de tu archivo, copia el path y pégalo. Tambien verifica que el nombre de los directorios sea correcto y esté escrito en el idioma de tu S.O.

Comment: Seguro tienes permisos para borrar ese archivo? Está realmente en el disco? Puede estar en tu OneDrive pero puede que esté "sólo en cloud", por lo que no habría un archivo realmente en tu disco...

Comment: Verifiqué todo antes de preguntar, la ruta es la correcta, los nombres son correctos, incluso probé con un archivo distinto para ver si el problema era ese file en particular pero tampoco lo eliminó

Comment: Si, tengo permisos para borrarlo y efectivamente está en el disco, incluso lo moví a otra ubicación y tampoco pude eliminarlo

Comment: Por eliminar posibles causas... prueba a ver con `os.system("del " + ubicacion)`, pues no estoy seguro de si `os.remove()` admite letra de unidad como parte de la ruta (y con `osssystem()` en realidad estaríamos usando una terminal cmd temporal que debería aceptarlo)

Comment: Acabo de probarlo, tampoco funciona os.system. No arroja error pero no lo elimina.

Comment: Y si abres una ventana cmd directamente en windows y dentro de ella haces un `del` de la ruta en cuestión, sin usar python para nada ¿te funciona?

Comment: Soy una idiota, efectivamente era un error del path. Por algún motivo, el archivo terminaba en .xlsm a pesar de que el resto eran .xls. Un millón de gracias!

Comment: Si encontraste la solución debes de ponerlo en la sección de comentarios no editar la pregunta!!

Comment: Gracias @Christian, soy nueva en esto, ya lo cambio!

Comment: Ya lo revertí, no te preocupes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se debe a que está incorrecta la sintaxis antes que todo y por tanto, usar `os.remove()` elimina el archivo de manera simple sin necesidad de agregar tanto código, por lo cual es recomendable que agregue el código completo, esta es la solución:

```
import os

ubicacion = (r"C:\Users\rbisa\OneDrive\Escritorio\prueba_eliminar.xls")
 
try:
    os.remove(ubicacion) 

except OSError as e:
    print("Error de archivo: {}".format(e))
```

Comment: Intenté con ese código y si bien no recibo error, me devuelve el mensaje "Error de archivo: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado: 'C:\\Users\\rbisa\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\prueba_eliminar.xls'" . Alguna idea de por que puede ser?

Comment: Ese mensaje que usted obtiene es un control de excepción en el bloque `try` y `except`, por lo cual `except` como excepción indica que ya no es problema del código si no que la ruta está mal escrita o el archivo está en otra ubicación, el archivo no existe o está mal escrito. Ese error ya es más de la ruta en el que se encuentra el archivo, por lo cual verifique la ruta o intente añadiendo el archivo en la carpeta de 'Descargas' u otra carpeta del sistema que tenga fácil acceso y no en subcarpetas.

Answer (score 2):

El error era del PATH finalmente, si tienen el mismo problema, recuerden chequear la terminación del archivo, uno suele concentrarse en las carpetas o el nombre, pero no siempre los archivos de excel son xls por default